# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for //: 'NoneType' and 'int'

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection

In ROI pooling, you have a region of interest(ROI) and you want to pool it to a specific size.

[ROI gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rJL7D.gif)

I try to implement the same thing like in the gif.
The whole image is

```
image_pl = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32)  # the whole region
```

the region of interest is

```
x = 0
y = 3
w = 7
h = -1
roi = tf.slice(image_pl, [x, y, 0], [w, h, -1])  # region of interest
```

Now I try to get the 4 parts, because every region of interest, no matter of their size, I want to crop to the size 2x2

```
w_roi = roi.get_shape()[0].value
h_roi = roi.get_shape()[1].value
roi_part1 = tf.slice(roi, [0, 0, 0], [w_roi // 2, h_roi // 2, -1]) # fisrt part from the gif
roi_part2 = tf.slice(roi, [w_roi - w_roi // 2, 0, 0], [w_roi, h_roi // 2, -1])  # second part from the gif
roi_part3 = tf.slice(roi, [0, h_roi - h_roi // 2, 0], [w_roi // 2, h_roi, -1])
roi_part4 = tf.slice(roi, [w_roi - w_roi // 2, h_roi - h_roi // 2, 0], [w_roi, h_roi, -1])
```

But here I get the error.

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for //: 'NoneType' and 'int'

Here is the whole code.
How can I implement the idea of that gif?

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

image_pl = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32)  # the whole region

x = 0
y = 3
w = 7
h = -1
roi = tf.slice(image_pl, [x, y, 0], [w, h, -1])  # region of interest

w_roi = roi.get_shape()[0].value
h_roi = roi.get_shape()[1].value
roi_part1 = tf.slice(roi, [0, 0, 0], [w_roi // 2, h_roi // 2, -1]) # fisrt part from the gif
roi_part2 = tf.slice(roi, [w_roi - w_roi // 2, 0, 0], [w_roi, h_roi // 2, -1])  # second part from the gif
roi_part3 = tf.slice(roi, [0, h_roi - h_roi // 2, 0], [w_roi // 2, h_roi, -1])
roi_part4 = tf.slice(roi, [w_roi - w_roi // 2, h_roi - h_roi // 2, 0], [w_roi, h_roi, -1])

output1 = tf.reduce_max(roi_part1)  # maximum of the region 1 in the region of interest
output2 = tf.reduce_max(roi_part2)
output3 = tf.reduce_max(roi_part3)
output4 = tf.reduce_max(roi_part4)
output = tf.concat([output1, output2, output3, output4], 0)

config = tf.ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
with tf.Session(config=config) as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    image = np.random.uniform(0, 1, (8, 8, 1))
    curr_image, curr_roi, curr_output = sess.run([image_pl, roi, output], feed_dict={image_pl: image})
```

Comment: Which line does throw the exception?

Comment: Seemingly `roi.get_shape()[i].value` has the value `None`. Did you confirm this by printing out `roi.get_shape()`?

Comment: thats right. its that line